# Initially fonts are blurry then back to normal

Tags: html, css, sass, fonts, webfonts

So finally I created a page with SCSS. But I am getting a problem.
I created this card and added scss. Initially, I get a text like this. But after few seconds it's back to what I needed. I have used google font link inside the head tag as well as imported inside scss. But the result is the same. This is only happening with text inside the cards.
So here is my SCSS

```css
.blogs {
  .card-heading {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    color: $card-head-color;
    font-weight: 500;
  }
  p.card-content {
    color: $secondary-color;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  .card-body {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 22px 0px #e0e0e0;
    background: #ffffff00;
    backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
    border: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 1.25rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="blogs">
<div class="card card-body mb-3 p-1">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4">
                  <img
                    src="https://www.visa.co.in/dam/VCOM/regional/ap/india/global-elements/images/in-visa-gold-card-498x280.png"
                    class="p-2 rounded"
                    style="height: 60px; width: 70px !important"
                    alt=""
                  />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8 pl-0">
                  <small
                    class="text-black text-truncate-3 mb-0 p-col"
                    style="font-weight: 500"
                  >
                    heading of the blog. It could be anything. It needs to be
                    inside this box.
                  </small>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

did you try smooth font?

```
.className{
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale; 
}
```

Comment: well thanks for the reply, but it didn't workout

Comment: if you share exactly same visual as a demo may be we can help you

Comment: did you try to remove backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
you dont need to give blur as extra option for the shadow. if you give it for the shadow

Comment: Its nothing to do with blur property. Actually, there was a mistake in my SCSS. That's why i was getting that problem. Thanx for your time.